# How can I use the WeDeploy API in my android project?

Tags: android, oauth, authorization, wedeploy

I want to use the `Auth` service provided by [WeDeploy](https://wedeploy.com/docs/auth/getting-started/) in my Android app but I don't know how can I get the access token when I'm redirecting to an activity using OAuth.

Answer (score 2):

You can try in your Activity:

```
Authorization authorization = TokenAuthorization.getAuthorizationFromIntent(getIntent());

String token = authorization.getToken();
```

You can find more info in the [docs](https://wedeploy.com/docs/auth/sign-in-with-facebook/)